# Ajax not loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am dynamically adding options to a drop down list with ajax jquery and PHP from my DB but for some reason it is not working. Please check my code:

**AJAX**

```
$("#course").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../ajax-select.php",
        data: id,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#sub").html(html);
        }  
    });    
});
```

**ajax-select.php**

```
<?php
if($_POST['id'])
{
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `subjects` WHERE `course_id`='$id'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $id=$row['sub_id'];
        $data=$row['sub_name'];
        echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" name="course" id="course">
        <option value="notselectedyear" selected>Select the Course</option>
              <?select_course();?>
        </select>
 </div>
 </p>
 <p>

<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Subject</span>
        <select class="form-control" name="sub" id="sub">
              <option value="notselectedsubject" selected>Select the subject</option>
        </select>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Additional info:

- Ids assigned to the select options are correct
- ajax code is in a folder called js whereas all other files are on the root
- Jquery is included before the closing of the body

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried making the url an absolute path, i.e. `url: "/ajax-select.php"`

Comment: try `data: "id="+id,` or `data: {id:id},`

Comment: Your SQL is open to SQL injection.

Comment: Are the "`" in your SQL query necessary? Also as user3558931 has stated, you are open to SQL injection. You should be using somethign like this http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php but figure your error out first.

Answer (score 1):

[**Concept Verification**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/3EUWL/1/)

Change:

```
data: id,
```

To:

```
data: {id: id},
```

If your content is dynamically generated (added after DOM ready) use the following:

```
$(document).on('change', '#course', function() 
{ 
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: I tried this. I am checking the console, no request is being sent to the server

Comment: Please post your HTML or create a jsfiddle.

Comment: @HetuNandu is your `$("#course").change(function() {` wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function(){` or `$(function(){`?

Comment: @Sean $(function(){ because it is at the end of the html

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Can we take a look at your live page?

Comment: Live page is protected but there are no errors of any sorts. There is nothing on the console at all! why would it not even send a xhr request??

Comment: Ok, take a look at the demo. You'll notice that I am using your exact code with the change suggested. The code attempts an ajax request each time the select is changed. The data being sent (via POST) is `id = n`. Compare the demo and your code; if you're running your code from a local drive please move it to a server.

Comment: @user3558931 Thanks. I am seeing the demo and my code matches yours exactly. Still i am not being able to send any xhr request. JS is working. All other functions working except this which is of AJAX

Comment: Okay i have drilled down the situation to this part: It is not listening to the change of drop down, thus the function is not working. how can i rectify that?